# error when copying UV maps

Tags: uv

I have two identical pipe objects(with different applied scale).

When I apply copy over the UV data to the unmapped object via CTRL+L > Copy UV maps, the UVs are correctly assigned, however the texture seems to break. I'm not sure if this is some kind of clipping or fighting issue.

Origin:

[image]

Destination:

[image]

Seems quite a broad topic, so I'm wondering why this particular thing could happen. If the UVs are the same for both objects and they both use the same material, why would there be such a large discrepancy? I noticed that the broken object doesn't have any seams marked, but from my understanding copying the UV data doesn't require seams.

Comment: The UV map copied correctly, but the geometry has different indices, and so the mapping is actually different.

Comment: is it possible to copy over the indices as well? or would you need to re-duplicate the mesh? sorry, I don't know where the indices are handled

Comment: First you could confirm if the indices are indeed wrong, by e.g. using MeasureIt add-on. Then, if it's not an issue, yes, duplicating the mesh again and observing what in your workflow scrambles (shuffles, reorders) the indices.